postgres: select and return results before dropping table
I have the following sql, where i want to return the selected data
insert into test(id,name) select * from tmp_tbl on conflict(id) do update set name = EXCLUDED.name;
with selected_data as (select * from tmp_tbl) select * from selected_data;
drop table if exists tmp_tbl;

THis is the python code:
with psycopg.connect(self.connect_str, autocommit=True) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute(sql_full)
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        colnames = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]
        df_result = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=colnames)                                       
        return df_result

This produces error:
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/psycopg/cursor.py", line 223, in fetchall
    self._check_result_for_fetch()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/psycopg/_cursor_base.py", line 588, in _check_result_for_fetch
    raise e.ProgrammingError("the last operation didn't produce a result")
psycopg.ProgrammingError: the last operation didn't produce a result

I can execute that sql directly in sql client(dbweaver) and it works. but the python/psycopg code does not.  any help appreciated

Send them as separate commands, probably wrapped in one transaction.

yeah. im trying to avoid round trips.

What does sql_full refer to? Add as text update to question text.


You are going to need to run the INSERT and SELECT as one operation  where you fetch the results into the dataframe and then run the DROP TABLE after that. Though if it is actually a TEMPORARY table it will be dropped at the completion of the session or using ON COMMIT at end of transaction. 2) You should look at Pipeline mode in psycopg.


I think the best option is to split the expression calls:
with psycopg.connect(…) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as curs:
        curs.execute(sql_1)
        …
        curs.execute(sql_2)
        …
        curs.execute(sql_3)

